# Windows behaves as if a key is constantly pressed

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse

Windows is showing weird behaviour, this happens without touching any button. I've used Passkmark KeyboardTest to verify.

[image]

- On Google Calendar it goes to the next momnth, in all browsers.
- When I click the speaker-icon on the task-bar it goes to maximize volume.
- Sometimes the text gets extremely zoomed out in Firefox, it might be
  at moments when I press ctrl, but not sure.
- On some sites it scrolls
  to the bottom or right.

I have the issue even when connecting from work via Teamviewer!

I installed software to see if keys were pressed, but no key was pressed either.

Windows showing weird behavior... as if keys are pressed that aren't pressed

Comment: Do you see this behavior if you unplug your mouse and keyboard? Are you using a laptop (potentially in a dock)?

Comment: It turned out to be the mouse constantly scrolling up.

Comment: Mice scrolls can be influenced by radio interference (phones, other wireless things).